Which part of the Bible supposedly talks of a leader with a mark on his forehead?
In one of the early chapters of Svetlana Alexievich's Chernobyl Prayer (or Voices from Chernobyl), a woman is cited saying the following (translation by Anna Gunin and Arch Tait, Penguin, 2016, page 54, emphasis mine):

What's written in the Bible is all coming true. In the Bible it says about our collective farm. And about Gorbachev. It says there'll be a big leader with a mark on his forehead, (…).

The Bible contains several passages about marks on foreheads, some of which are cited below.
Ezekiel 9:4–6 (the slaughter of the idolaters):

4 And the LORD said unto him, Go through the midst of the city, through the midst of Jerusalem, and set a mark upon the foreheads of the men that sigh and that cry for all the abominations that be done in the midst thereof.
5 And to the others he said in mine hearing, Go ye after him through the city, and smite: let not your eye spare, neither have ye pity:
6 Slay utterly old and young, both maids, and little children, and women: but come not near any man upon whom is the mark; and begin at my sanctuary. Then they began at the ancient men which were before the house.

Revelation 14:9:

And the third angel followed them, saying with a loud voice, If any man worship the beast and his image, and receive his mark in his forehead, or in his hand,

This mark is also known as the mark of the beast, which, to my mind, is not the mark of a great leader.
Revelation 17:5:

And upon her forehead was a name written, MYSTERY, BABYLON THE GREAT, THE MOTHER OF HARLOTS AND ABOMINATIONS OF THE EARTH.

This is from a passage that has been referred to as "Babylon, the Prostitute on the Beast", which is probably not what the woman meant either.
I have found several other passages that involve a mark on the forehead, but none of them seem to be about a big leader. Am I overlooking the correct Bible passage?

I suppose it refers to the mark of Cain in Genesis. Not exactly a leader... but might fit the context otherwise.

The woman is referring to Gorbachev as the first Beast from Revelation, who is given authority by the Dragon (representing Satan). According to Revelation 13:1-7:

And I stood upon the sand of the sea, and saw a beast rise up out of the sea, having seven heads and ten horns, and upon his horns ten crowns, and upon his heads the name of blasphemy.
And the beast which I saw was like unto a leopard, and his feet were as the feet of a bear, and his mouth as the mouth of a lion: and the dragon gave him his power, and his seat, and great authority.
And I saw one of his heads as it were wounded to death; and his deadly wound was healed: and all the world wondered after the beast.
And they worshipped the dragon which gave power unto the beast: and they worshipped the beast, saying, Who is like unto the beast? who is able to make war with him?
And there was given unto him a mouth speaking great things and blasphemies; and power was given unto him to continue forty and two months.
And he opened his mouth in blasphemy against God, to blaspheme his name, and his tabernacle, and them that dwell in heaven.
And it was given unto him to make war with the saints, and to overcome them: and power was given him over all kindreds, and tongues, and nations.

Then in verses 16-17 of the same chapter:

And he [a second Beast] causeth all, both small and great, rich and poor, free and bond, to receive a mark in their right hand, or in their foreheads:
And that no man might buy or sell, save he that had the mark, or the name of the beast, or the number of his name.

The woman is conflating two different statements: The Beast itself has a wound on its head; its worshipers receive a mark on their foreheads (or hands). Thus, the Beast fits the description "a big leader with [something] on his [fore]head," but the specific term "mark" pertains to his followers, not him.
There is a long history of people slightly twisting the words of Revelation 13 to make them apply to whatever event or leader is on their minds at the moment. It's no surprise that Gorbachev got the same treatment.
